# Identify commits that have been squashed using rebase -i

Tags: git, bash, rebase

I am wondering if it is possible to identify the number of commits that have been rebased and squashed in a given project. I can settle for all rebases and not just the ones that performed a squash.

I'm essentially trying to write a function that can count the number of rebases a user has ran for a given project.

For example if I have a project with three commits with the following hashes `1234`, `5678`, `9999`. 
 I want to be able to identify that commit `1234` originally was commit `1111` and `2222` but was rebased and squashed together to make the commit `1234`.

Similarly, I can find what commits were created with a merge by running `git log | grep -i merge`.

Ideally this will be a one liner similar to the command just mentioned.

From my own experience squashing two or more commits into one results in the rebased commit containing all of the commit messages joined by a newline (assuming none of the commit messages are edited during the rebasing). With this information it does not seem possible. Yet, I'm asking because I would love to be able to do this as it will help my project immensely.

TLDR: One liner to find the commits that were created by a rebase. Does Git do anything special to mark rebased commits?

Comment: "From my own experience squashing two or more commits into one results in the rebased commit containing all of the commit messages joined by a newline." -- Not even that. That's just the default. The message may be edited to anything, during or after a rebase. But then again, a merge commit does not necessarily contain the word "merge" in its message. It's not clear what assumptions you can make without a lot more info about your project.

Comment: @hvd Yes, I was making the assumption that none of the commit messages were edited during the rebase. See edited question.

Comment: For your local repos, you can get a rough estimate using reflog: `git reflog | awk 'BEGIN { n = 0 } /rebase -i/ { n += 1; next } { if (n) print n; n = 0 } END { if (n) print n }'`

Comment: @eush77 this returned 3 when it ran on a repo with 2 commits, one being a rebase of 2 commits. So, if you create an answer for this explaining your thought process maybe we can take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this task using `git reflog`.

`git reflog` gives me all actions *including the rebases*.

Typical output is as follows:

```
some-computer:test_project marcusshepherd$ git reflog
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
47066c8 HEAD@{0}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/master
47066c8 HEAD@{1}: rebase -i (squash): add bar.txt
ae35743 HEAD@{2}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~2
7c5b185 HEAD@{3}: commit: edit bar.txt
ae35743 HEAD@{4}: commit: add bar.txt
a9b6aa1 HEAD@{5}: commit (initial): init
```

With this information I was able to find all the commands that contain both the strings `rebase` and `finish` then count them. This gives me the correct number of rebases for any given project.

Must say I'm quite happy to have solved this problem.